# OpenCV Nvidia Optical Flow SDK2.0 enableExternalHints fails

Tags: opencv, parameters, nvidia, opticalflow

When running the python wrapper for OpenCV's NvidiaOpticalFlow_2_0 create function,

```
nvof2 = cv.cuda_NvidiaOpticalFlow_2_0.create((sz,sz), outputGridSize = OFres, perfPreset = nvperf, enableExternalHints = True)
```

I get the error,

```
error: (-5:Bad argument) GetAPI()->nvOFInit(GetHandle(), &m_initParams) returned error 5:NV_OF_ERR_INVALID_PARAM in function 'NvidiaOpticalFlowImpl_2'
```

Running the SDK 1.0 version with hints turned on,

```
nvof = cv.cuda_NvidiaOpticalFlow_1_0.create((sz,sz), nvperf, False, True, False)
```

works just fine and I can see the effect of my hints on the flow field the calc() function produces. I can also avoid the error in the 2.0 SDK by turning off external hints, but of course that is not what I want,

```
nvof2 = cv.cuda_NvidiaOpticalFlow_2_0.create((sz,sz), outputGridSize = OFres, perfPreset = nvperf, enableExternalHints = False)
```

Can anyone confirm if cv.cuda_NvidiaOpticalFlow_2_0.create is able to handle external hints as of OpenCV 4.7.0? It seems strange if not because it works with the 1.0 SDK but I don't see what else could be causing this error.